# How to merge Javascript Object in array using reduce or array method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to merge the same id, but it's not as easy as I thought. Can you help me?

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, stats: {kill:7, de: 3, as: 8}, wins: true},
  {id: 2, stats: {kill:1, de: 3, as: 8}, wins: false},
  {id: 2, stats: {kill:17, de: 9, as: 3}, wins: true},
  {id: 1, stats: {kill:6, de: 2, as: 1}, wins: true},
];
```

My code  until now

```
 const result = data.reduce((b,c) => ((b[b.findIndex(d => d.id === c.id)] || b[b.push({
      id: c.id,
      stats: c.stats.kill,
      count: 0,
    }) - 1]).count++, b), []);
```

goal

```
[
  {id: 1, stats: {kill: 13, de: 5, as: 9}, victoryRate: '100%', count:2},
  {id: 2, stats: {kill: 18, de: 12, as: 11}, victoryRate: '50%', count: 2}
]
```

If it is difficult to answer, please recommend Keyword so that I can do it myself!

Thanks

Comment: Please [**search**](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+merge+objects+by+key) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'll search more before I start asking questions.

Comment: const resultObj = data.reduce( (obj,val) => {
    if (obj[val.id]) {
        obj[val.id].stats.kill = obj[val.id].stats.kill + val.stats.kill;
        obj[val.id].stats.de = obj[val.id].stats.de + val.stats.de;
        obj[val.id].stats.as = obj[val.id].stats.as + val.stats.as;
        obj[val.id].wins = obj[val.id].wins + val.wins;
        obj[val.id].count = obj[val.id].count + 1;
        obj[val.id].victoryRate = Math.round( obj[val.id].wins / obj[val.id].count * 100 ) + '%';
    } else {
        obj[val.id] = val;
        obj[val.id].count = 1;
    }
    return obj;
}, {});

Comment: const result = Object.values(resultObj);

result.forEach(element => {
    delete element.wins;
});

console.log(result);

Comment: <script>
const data = [
    {id: 1, stats: {kill:7, de: 3, as: 8}, wins: true},
  {id: 2, stats: {kill:1, de: 3, as: 8}, wins: false},
  {id: 2, stats: {kill:17, de: 9, as: 3}, wins: true},
  {id: 1, stats: {kill:6, de: 2, as: 1}, wins: true},
];
ids=[];

data.forEach(function(d) {
   ids.push(d.id); 
});

u_ids = ids.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return ids.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
result=[];
for(var i=0;i<u_ids.length;i++){
var kill=0;
var win=0;
var loss=0;
var de=0;
var as=0;
count=0;

Comment: for(var j=0;j<data.length;j++){
    if(ids[i]===data[j].id){
 kill+=data[j].stats.kill;
 de+=data[j].stats.de;
 as+=data[j].stats.as;
 count++;
 if(true==data[j].wins){
  win++;
 }else{
  loss++;
 }
       }
}
result.push({id:ids[i], stats: {kill: kill, de:de, as:as}, victoryRate:(win/(loss+win)*100)+'%', count:count});
}
console.log(result);

</script>